# Highcharts Transition from Column to Spiderweb

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have been trying to use highcharts to render a simple column chart. I've been having a couple of issues with it. Initially I set up a column chart, which works just fine. I want to turn it into a spiderweb chart (with different data) upon clicking a button. I've turned the chart.polar to true in the button click, but it renders the chart as a line chart instead of a spider web. Am I missing something here?
This is the code in my button click function:

```
$('#spider_button').on('click', function () {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'main_chart_container';
        options.chart.polar = true;
        options.chart.type = 'line';
        options.xAxis.categories = ['Quarter 1', 'Quarter 2', 'Quarter 3', 'Quarter 4'];
        options.title.text = 'Daily UFO Sightings';
        options.series = [{"data": [129, 105, 149, 115], "name": "Triangle"}, {"data": [121, 100, 131, 78], "name": "Fireball"}, {"data": [56, 50, 46, 47], "name": "Formation"}, {"data": [279, 240, 310, 289], "name": "Light"}, {"data": [153, 196, 182, 147], "name": "Circle"}, {"data": [13, 16, 17, 22], "name": "Chevron"}, {"data": [4, 8, 12, 7], "name": "Egg"}, {"data": [14, 16, 14, 20], "name": "Diamond"}, {"data": [18, 24, 15, 15], "name": "Cylinder"}, {"data": [58, 49, 54, 49], "name": "Disk"}, {"data": [31, 28, 37, 24], "name": "Changing"}];
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adway/gv7a6ngg/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polar charts require highcharts-more.js. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.polar

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gv7a6ngg/9/